# Angular (V.8+) and BigInts

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if I need to worry about browser compatability if I am serving an Angular application which consists of classes which use helper classes which use bigints and the shorthand `let x = 10n` sort of thing.  In order to use `let x = 10n` I need to target ESNext in my tsconfig, but I understand that TS will then produce javascript that normally wouldn't run on non-chrome browsers (like safari for example).

However I'm under the vague impression that current version of Node does support BigInt, and Angular incorporates Node into various build tools, so I'm wondering if the BigInt problem magically goes away if I am using BigInt within an Angular application?    I use bigint in classes that represent models, not directly in Angular controller code.   Will I still have problems on Firefox running my Angular application with bigint usage in these classes?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in FF and other browsers? where are you stuck?

Comment: I am writing the classes that will support the angular application at this point.  My jasmine tests run fine in Chrome, but if I run them on Safara, I get an error the first time I try to use the bigint literal syntax let i = 10n say;

Comment: what is the exact error that you get

Comment: `SyntaxError: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js line 976` which occurs at the line when n is used to modify a number to be a bigint.